# Script is failing before reach the clause - Selenium - C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have selenium script, with If clause, so whenever the element is present click on it, else return message.

```
If (driver.FindElement(By.Id("id")).Enabled)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("id")).Click();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Logout button was not visible!");
}
```

The element is not present, and test is failing before reach the If statement.
I tried with both `.Displayed` / `.Enabled`

Comment: Have you tried putting in a delay for the page to finish loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the logout element was not loaded before you tried clicking it, you can use `WebDriverWait` to wait until the element is clickable. Add the following line to the top of your .cs file

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

Then, try this:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

try
{
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("id"))).Click();
}
catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Logout button was not visible!");
}
```

The `WebDriverWait wait` will wait up to 10 seconds before throwing a timeout, if it throws a timeout you can write to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try catch block to handle the exception, you may need an explicit wait aswell.

```
try
{
driver.FindElement(By.Id("id")).Enabled;
driver.FindElement(By.Id("id")).Click();
}
catch
{
Console.WriteLine("Logout button was not visible!");
}
```